# Add image from upload input to database

Tags: c#, image

What i want to do is to add my image to my sql database. Currently i have this code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=Authorship;Integrated Security =True");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        cmd.Connection = con; //assigning connection to command
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; //representing type of command
        //cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO UserDetails (Fname,Lname,Email,Password,Gender,Dob,Mobile,Address) values
        // (@Fname,@Lname,@Email,@Password,@Gender,@Dob,@Mobile,@Address)";
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Products values(@Name,@Description,@Image,@Quantity,@ProductPrice)";

        //adding parameters with value
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", TextBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", FileUpload1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", TextBox4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductPrice", TextBox4.Text);

        con.Open(); //opening connection
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  //executing query
        con.Close(); //closing connection
        Label1.Text = "Added Successfully..";

    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "Not successful";
    }
```

i am having this error:

> No mapping exists from object type
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload to a known managed provider
>   native type.

any idea what should i write in my

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", FileUpload1.????);
```

thank you!

Comment: What is the type of `Image` column that you try to insert?

Comment: in database? datatype is image.

Comment: im trying to insert jpg files

Comment: I think you need to get `FileUpload1.FileBytes` then push it into string and send to database.

Comment: By the way, `image` type will be removed future SQL Server versions. Consider to change your column type to `varbinary(max)`.

Comment: you're very helpful. got it. kindly post an answer and i will mark it. :) @SonerGönül

Answer (score 0):

You need to get `var input = FileUpload1.FileBytes`.
Then push this content to string:

```
// Copy the byte array to a string.
for (int loop = 0; loop < input.length; loop++) {
  displayString = displayString + input[loop].ToString();
}
```

Then send it to database:

`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", displayString);`

As @Soner Gönül suggested in comments:

> By the way, image type will be removed future SQL Server versions.
>   Consider to change your column type to varbinary(max).